# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to bug this out but I can't find any solution.

This is the C# code.

```
string unraw_json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var objects = JArray.Parse(unraw_json);

            foreach (JObject items in objects)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in items)
                {
                    var appName = app.Key;
                    var username = (String)app.Value["username"];
                    var password = (String)app.Value["password"];
```

When debugging `var appName = "username"` while when I reach `var username` (line 9), it throws me that error.

I've already tried to include the json inside brace brackets but it throws me an error on the `var appName`. I've also tried to use different parsing and different libraries but I wanted to used the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq library. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

This is the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "toor"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `foreach` iterates over *each* `KeyValuePair` in `items`. `app` is a `KeyValuePair<String, JToken>` where the *key* is `"username"` and the *value* is a `JToken` string containing `"root"`. You're doing your `["username"]` and `["password"]` indexing one layer too deep.

Since you already know which keys you want, you don't need to iterate over `items` at all. Just index `items` directly:

```
    foreach (JObject items in objects)
    {
        var username = (String)items["username"];
        var password = (String)items["password"];
    }
```